# monerod --p2p-bind-ip doesn't work correctly 0.14.x

Tags: monerod

When using a multi-homed server trying to get monerod to use a specific IP address with --p2p-bind-ip will produce the expected listening socket on IP:PORT specified, but will send OUT using a different IP address.

--p2p-bind-ip is broken

Comment: This is an existing [issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/838) logged on GitHub. It's not that `--p2p-bind-ip` is "broken" per se, rather it currently just binds the p2p *listening* interface IP.

Comment: Also addressed in [p2p: connect via the bound ip, if any](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4089) and here [Revert "p2p: connect via the bound ip, if any"](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4578). The revert broke my "private testnet".